# How to set a image selection limit using intent in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to select only 5 images from the gallery. Here I shared my code. Can anyone help?

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
// var intent = Intent(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY)
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
intent.putExtra(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY,true)
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
intent.type = "image/*"

startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE)
```

Comment: Good question..